# How to determine why Apple is replying with "We were unable to review your app"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash-reports

Apple has rejected my app 2 times with the message: "We were unable to review your app..." that many of you know.

I have symbolicated the full log, but still cannot find the error cause for this.

```
CrashReporter Key:   318083a7319cbe05fd01b4c953a58aebe938f998
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             LoLQuotes [6832]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8FAD465-FF72-4926-8B12-1D243F46005B/LoLQuotes.app/LoLQuotes
Identifier:          br.Aenyxes.LoLQuotes
Version:             6 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           br.Aenyxes.LoLQuotes [3163]


Date/Time:           2018-01-19 13:25:28.2451 -0800
Launch Time:         2018-01-19 13:25:27.5412 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.2 (15C202)
Baseband Version:    6.30.04
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100840ba0
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   LoLQuotes                       0x0000000100840ba0 0x10081c000 + 150432
1   LoLQuotes                       0x000000010083fbe4 0x10081c000 + 146404
2   UIKit                           0x000000018f073a50 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 248
3   UIKit                           0x000000018f2213ac UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 688
4   UIKit                           0x000000018f221524 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1064
5   UIKit                           0x000000018f2210e4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 104
6   UIKit                           0x000000018ee4d6a0 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 1424
7   UIKit                           0x000000018ee69db8 -[UINavigationController initWithCoder:] + 76
8   UIKit                           0x000000018f2213ac UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 688
9   UIKit                           0x000000018f2210e4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 104
10  UIKit                           0x000000018f0736f4 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 188
11  UIKit                           0x000000018f2213ac UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 688
12  UIKit                           0x000000018f221524 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1064
13  UIKit                           0x000000018f2210e4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 104
14  UIKit                           0x000000018f072a34 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1168
15  UIKit                           0x000000018f3f7ec4 -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 196
16  UIKit                           0x000000018ed46c80 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 124
17  UIKit                           0x000000018eb4f008 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 264
18  UIKit                           0x000000018ed45984 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1420
19  UIKit                           0x000000018efe12d4 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 800
20  UIKit                           0x000000018f2b912c +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
21  UIKit                           0x000000018efe0f38 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 252
22  UIKit                           0x000000018efe1798 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 732
23  UIKit                           0x000000018f7667d0 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 260
24  UIKit                           0x000000018f766674 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
25  UIKit                           0x000000018f4d42dc __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
26  UIKit                           0x000000018f66d3dc _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
27  UIKit                           0x000000018f4d418c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 252
28  UIKit                           0x000000018f2b878c -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 364
29  UIKit                           0x000000018ed441ec -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
30  UIKit                           0x000000018f159de8 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364
31  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000187bee1f0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364
32  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000187bf6af8 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224
33  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184ea6a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
34  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184eae200 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288
35  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000187c227f8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
36  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000187c2249c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
37  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000187c22a38 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
38  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001854d297c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
39  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001854d28fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
40  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001854d2184 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
41  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001854cfd5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
42  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001853efe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
43  GraphicsServices                0x000000018729cf84 GSEventRunModal + 100
44  UIKit                           0x000000018eb4467c UIApplicationMain + 236
45  LoLQuotes                       0x0000000100823ea0 0x10081c000 + 32416
46  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000184f0c56c start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018503cd80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018514f080 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018514eb6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018503cd80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018514f080 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018514eb6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018514eb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018514eb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018501b568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018501b3e0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001854d2308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001854cfed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001853efe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x0000000185e25594 -[NSRunLoop+ 50580 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x0000000185e449ac -[NSRunLoop+ 178604 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000018f6ae7b8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x0000000185f270f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001851502b4 _pthread_body + 308
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185150180 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018514eb74 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018514eb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000101114900   x1: 0x00000001c4048f10   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x0000000185083318
    x4: 0x00000001c40f1a00   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000001c404f210   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0xbaddc0dedeadbead
   x12: 0x00000001b8694e1c  x13: 0x0000000000000054  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0x0000000000000881
   x16: 0x000000018514a8cc  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0xfffffff02129925c  x19: 0x0000000108814800
   x20: 0x0000000107e0b4a0  x21: 0x00000001b6390b58  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x00000001c4048f10
   x24: 0x00000001008d5000  x25: 0x00000001b4f41000  x26: 0x00000001b4f41000  x27: 0x00000001b4f41000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016f5e06e0   lr: 0x0000000100840ae0
    sp: 0x000000016f5e06a0   pc: 0x0000000100840ba0 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

My app contains a Widget system, don't know if this helps with the crashlog, but if so.

Comment: Have you used TestFlight to run your app on a device?  Does it work?  It looks like you have a missing IBOutlet connection from your storyboard, but that is just a guess.  It could also be a missing framework or library from your release build; Certainly something went wrong creating your initial view controller from the storyboard

Comment: @Paulw11 I`m testing on TestFlight and really something is crashing the app on launch, even the Quick Actions does not have it's pictures. Do you think it's about compression ?

Comment: Try logging code to find where the crash is. You can use something like NSLogger, or log to a cloud service. Put logging messages in various places in your AppDelegate, and see which execute before the crash, then do again, etc until you pinpoint the line of code where it occurs. If it happens before code is executed, then @Paulw11is likely right.

Comment: I doubt that it is anything to do with compression.  It looks like your storyboard scene contains a reference to a class that could not be found at runtime.

Comment: You need to symbolicate this log against the symbols for the build being reviewed so you can where in your own code it is failing.